# how to get $(this) inside of backbone.js event

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I need to find out, on what element, with particular class, was triggered jquery callback. For example, if I have this jquery:

```
 $('#content').delegate('.role', 'change', function(e){
    if($(this).val() == 'Student'){
      $('.roleStudent').show();
      $('.roleTeacher').hide();
    }else if($(this).val() == 'Teacher'){
      $('.roleTeacher').show();
      $('.roleStudent').hide();
    }else if($(this).val() == 'User'){
      $('.roleTeacher').hide();
      $('.roleStudent').hide();
    }
  });
```

, and I need to create out of it an backbone event. It must look some kind like this:

```
events: {
    'change .role' : changeRole
}
```

and inside `changeRole` functioin a need to find out, what select with class `.role` was change, so I can build my statement like so:

```
       if($(this).val() == 'Student'){
          $('.roleStudent').show();
          $('.roleTeacher').hide();
        }else if($(this).val() == 'Teacher'){
          $('.roleTeacher').show();
          $('.roleStudent').hide();
        }else if($(this).val() == 'User'){
          $('.roleTeacher').hide();
          $('.roleStudent').hide();
        }
```

Thank you all for any advises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone provides an event as a first argument for such kind of tasks:

```
changeRole : function (e) {
  var value = e.currentTarget.value;
}
```

And `currentTarget` property of this event is an element you a looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
changeRole: function(event){
    var val = this.$(event.currentTarget).val();
    switch(val){
        case 'Student':
            $('.roleStudent').show();
            $('.roleTeacher').hide();
            break;
        case 'Teacher':
            $('.roleTeacher').show();
            $('.roleStudent').hide();
            break;
        case 'User':
            $('.roleTeacher').hide();
            $('.roleStudent').hide();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but Vitaliy was first ))